# Is there a way to prepend "text" to a string before the "."? Example: 10.jpg

Tags: php, file, prepend

I have different sizes of photos, but I have 1 file name in the database. However, depending on the situation I want to use a different file size. For instance:

```
10.jpg
```

This is the username and the extension, but the extension and user ID can/will vary between `.jpg, .jpeg, and .png` so I wont know the exact file extension at every given moment.
All of my file types are as followed:

```
10-thumbnail.jpg // chat size
10-profile.jpg //profile pic preview
10.jpg //full size
```

When echoing out the photo, I usually just do the path of the image after getting it from the database.
`echo $profilepic; //10.jpg`
However, without having to make a separate column for each version of the photo, id just like to be able to manipulate the current image name to include something like `10-profile.jpg`. Is there a way to just add the `-profile` before the `.`? Since the user ID and the extension could/will be different. Do I need to explode?
Thanks!

Comment: Wait a minute; you state in your question that you want to "prepend". What was given in both answers below are "appending"; is there something that I missed or didn't understand? Adding something before a dot, I don't think qualifies as prepending, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow for flexibility in the usernames (e.g. to include a `.`), I would use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) to find the last `.` in the filename and insert the size before it:

```
$filename = '10.jpg';
$size = 'profile';
echo preg_replace('/(\.[^.]*)$/', "-$size$1", $filename);
$filename = 'john.smith.jpg';
$size = 'profile';
echo preg_replace('/(\.[^.]*)$/', "-$size$1", $filename);
```

Output:

```
10-profile.jpg
john.smith-profile.jpg
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YPsVk)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to explode the string on the '.'.

Here is an example:

```php
$profilepic = '10.jpg';
$explode = explode('.', $profilepic);
$text = $explode[0] . '-text' . '.' . $explode[1];
var_dump($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the details in your question, I understand that:

- the user ID is a variable integer,
- the image type can vary.

Thus, your full-size-picture-name column will be contain values such as '1.jpg', '2.png', …, '748.gif', *etc.*

In this situation, I would simply use `str_replace()`:

```
<?php
$fullsizepic = '10.jpg';
echo $profilepic = str_replace('.', '-profile.', $fullsizepic); // 10-profile.jpg
?>
```

Best regards